# copy files from one laptop to another using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am absolute newbie when it comes to powershell. What I want to do is copy one file from my computer to another computer on same network using powershell . 
I tried

```
robocpy  ROBOCOPY \\C:\try.txt \\192.168.0.54\Users\Desktop\  /Z
```

but it says

> ERROR 53 (0x00000035)
>   The network path was not found.

how to do it?

Comment: That question better fits in [SU]. The backslashes `\\\`in front of your local file are wrong, simply leave them away. And the destination needs an `C$` for an admin share following the IP or an other share name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities to do so.
Yo said you would like to use powershell but than using ROBOCOPY which is actually just a program that you can start in powershell or the old cmd promt.

In powerhsell this could work:

```
Copy-Item -Path \\serverB\c$\temp\test.txt -Destination \\serverA\c$\tmp\test.txt;
```

Note: as this is using the administartive shares it needs a user who has administrative access on both machines (serverA & serverB)

Still it is possible to use Robocopy.
But as your error stated: *The network path was not found.* 
Should it exist ? did you shared that folder? does the user have access?
First try local coping, than via netshare. If the user has no admin privileges you should share folder from the destination machine.